# How to fix duplicate data when use Fragment and TabLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-event

I want show website datas in 3 `fragments` with **`json`**! when swipe between **TAB**s not duplicate datas. but when click on **TAB**s, duplicate previous data again!
For send data from from **`AsyncTask`** to Fragments i use **`EventBus`** component.
**Fragment codes:**

```
public class free_fragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private free_recycler_adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private List<DataModel> dataModels = new ArrayList<DataModel>();

    private Context context;
    private boolean isDataFetched;
    private boolean mIsVisibleToUser;
    private View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_free_layout, container, false);

        context = getContext();

        if (mIsVisibleToUser) {
            LoadData();
        }

        ///----- RecyclerView -----
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.pdf_RecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mAdapter = new free_recycler_adapter(context, dataModels);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        return view;
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onEvent(MyEvent event) {
        List<DataModel> dataModels = event.getInfoModels();
/*        if (dataModels.size() > 0) {
            dataModels.remove(dataModels.size() - 1);
            mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(dataModels.size());
            //mAdapter.setLoaded();
        }*/
        if (event.fragmentTag.equals("forfragment1")) {
            mAdapter.add(dataModels);
            isDataFetched = true;
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        mIsVisibleToUser = isVisibleToUser;
        if (isVisibleToUser && !isDataFetched && getContext() != null) {
            context = getContext();
            LoadData(); //Remove this call from onCreateView
        }
    }

    private void LoadData() {
        freeDataInfo dataInfo = new freeDataInfo();
        // here getMainDataInfo() should return the server response
        dataInfo.getFreeDataInfo(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

**AsyncTask codes:**

```
public class freeDataInfo {
    private Context mContext;
    private String ServerAddress = freeServer_IP.getFreeIP();
    private DiskLruDataCache mDiskLruCache;

    public void getFreeDataInfo(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        this.mDiskLruCache=new DiskLruDataCache(context);
        //new getInfo().execute(ServerAddress + "limit=10");
        new getInfo().execute(ServerAddress);
    }

    private class getInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        EventBus bus = EventBus.getDefault();
        private String ou_response;
        private List<DataModel> infoModels = new ArrayList<>();
        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //CustomProcessDialog.createAndShow(mContext);
            //infoModels = new ArrayList<>();

            // Initiate Progress
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
            this.dialog.setMessage("شکیبا باشید...");
            this.dialog.show();

            infoModels.clear();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            //String url = (String) params[0];
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    //.url(ServerAddress + "limit=10")
                    .url(ServerAddress)
                    .cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK)
                    .build();

            Response response;
            try {
                if(CheckInternet.isConnected(mContext)) {
                    response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                    ou_response = response.body().string();
                    if (ou_response != null) {
                        mDiskLruCache.cacheToDisk(ServerAddress, ou_response);
                    }
                    response.body().close();
                }
                else{
                    ou_response=mDiskLruCache.fetchFromDiskCache(ServerAddress);
                }
                if (ou_response != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject postObj = new JSONObject(ou_response);
                        JSONArray postsArray = postObj.optJSONArray("result");

                        for (int i = 0; i <= postsArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject postObject = (JSONObject) postsArray.get(i);


                            int id = postObject.getInt("id");
                            Log.d("id", String.valueOf(id));
                            String title = postObject.getString("title");
                            String description = postObject.getString("full_description");
                            String image = postObject.getString("image");
                            String category = postObject.getString("categoryName");
                            String date = postObject.getString("date");
                            String url = postObject.getString("url");

                            Log.d("Data", "Post ID: " + id);
                            Log.d("Data", "Post title: " + title);
                            Log.d("Data", "Post image: " + image);
                            Log.d("Data", "Post url: " + url);
                            Log.d("Data", "---------------------------------");

                            //Use the title and id as per your requirement
                            infoModels.add(new DataModel(id, title, description, category, date, url, image));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("error", String.valueOf(e));
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("error2", String.valueOf(e));
            }
            return ou_response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //CustomProcessDialog.dissmis();

            //Stop Progress
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

            if (result != null) {
                bus.post(new MyEvent("forfragment1", infoModels));
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Check Internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Adapter Codes:**

```
public class free_recycler_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<free_recycler_adapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<DataModel> mDateSet;
    private Context context;

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public free_recycler_adapter(Context context, List<DataModel> dataSet) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mDateSet = dataSet;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public free_recycler_adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.free_card_layout, parent, false);

        // create ViewHolder
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

        // - get data from your itemsData at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that itemsData

        viewHolder.free_titleText.setText(Html.fromHtml(mDateSet.get(position).getTitle()));
        viewHolder.free_titleText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), ContentPage.class)
                        .putExtra("title", mDateSet.get(position).getTitle())
                        .putExtra("desc", mDateSet.get(position).getDescription())
                        .putExtra("image", mDateSet.get(position).getImage())
                        .putExtra("url", mDateSet.get(position).getUrl())
                        .putExtra("category", mDateSet.get(position).getCategory())
                        .putExtra("date", mDateSet.get(position).getDate()));
            }
        });

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(mDateSet.get(position).getImage())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_download_image)
                .crossFade()
                .into(viewHolder.free_avatarImage);
        viewHolder.free_avatarImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), ContentPage.class)
                        .putExtra("title", mDateSet.get(position).getTitle())
                        .putExtra("desc", mDateSet.get(position).getDescription())
                        .putExtra("image", mDateSet.get(position).getImage())
                        .putExtra("url", mDateSet.get(position).getUrl())
                        .putExtra("category", mDateSet.get(position).getCategory())
                        .putExtra("date", mDateSet.get(position).getDate()));
            }
        });

        viewHolder.free_descText.setText(Html.fromHtml(mDateSet.get(position).getDescription()));
        viewHolder.free_descText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), ContentPage.class)
                        .putExtra("title", mDateSet.get(position).getTitle())
                        .putExtra("desc", mDateSet.get(position).getDescription())
                        .putExtra("image", mDateSet.get(position).getImage())
                        .putExtra("url", mDateSet.get(position).getUrl())
                        .putExtra("category", mDateSet.get(position).getCategory())
                        .putExtra("date", mDateSet.get(position).getDate()));
            }
        });

    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDateSet.size();
    }

    public void remove(int position) {
        mDateSet.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    public void clear() {
        mDateSet.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void add(List<DataModel> models) {
        mDateSet.addAll(models);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void update(List<DataModel> models) {
        mDateSet.clear();
        mDateSet.addAll(models);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    // inner class to hold a reference to each item of RecyclerView
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView free_titleText, free_descText;
        public ImageView free_avatarImage;

        public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);

            free_titleText = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.pdf_card_title);
            free_descText = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.pdf_card_content);
            free_avatarImage = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.pdf_card_image);

        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity codes:**

```
public class Main_Page extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CollapsingToolbarLayout mCollapsingToolbarLayout;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private NavigationView nvDrawer;
    private ImageView menuImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main__page);

        CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/iransans.ttf")
                .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                .build());

        mCollapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar_layout);
        //mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();

        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        menuImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.DrawableMenu_image);
        menuImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Adding custom view to tab
     */
    private void setupTabIcons() {

        TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabOne.setText(R.string.free_fragment_title);
        tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_download_image, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);

        TextView tabTwo = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabTwo.setText(R.string.paid_fragment_title);
        tabTwo.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_paid_download_image, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);

        TextView tabThree = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabThree.setText(R.string.pdf_fragment_title);
        tabThree.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_pdf_icon, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(tabThree);
    }

    /**
     * Adding fragments to ViewPager
     *
     * @param viewPager
     */
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new free_fragment(), "رایگان ها");
        adapter.addFrag(new paid_fragment(), "پرداختی ها");
        adapter.addFrag(new pdf_fragment(), "مقالات");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mDrawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
            mDrawer.closeDrawers();
        } else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }

}
```

How can i fix this and not duplicate datas when click on **`TabLayout`** ?
I am amateur and i really need this help, please help me. Thanks all<3

Comment: You are calling mAdapter.add(dataModels) every time the event is triggered. You can comment it out and only call notify dataset changed on Adapter. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @AlokOmkar, can you send me true code? i am amateur . please

Comment: You need to clear your arraylist before add data in it out of for loop

Answer (score 0):

Check the commented code : It's causing the dataModels to be added every time to your adapter.

```
@Subscribe
public void onEvent(MyEvent event) {
       List<DataModel> dataModels = event.getInfoModels();

       if (event.fragmentTag.equals("forfragment1")) {
                //mAdapter.add(dataModels);
                isDataFetched = true;
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
}
```

- In your adapter, in add() method, you are adding the data to the list all over again, this is unnecessary, calling notifyDataSetChanged automatically intimates the adapter that the original data has been changed.
- Just call notifyDataSetChanged on adapter to refresh the updated data. Hope it helps.

Comment: when remove `mAdapter.add(dataModels);` , not load datas !

Comment: Can you check how many times the onEvent is being triggered? It should only be triggered once. Check the response from server. In case there are duplicates present, eliminate them.